# Backbone event aggregators

Tags: events, backbone.js, underscore.js

What's the difference between using `_.extend({}, Backbone.Events)` and `_.clone(Backbone.Events)` for an event aggregator? I have seen them both used for this purpose:

http://backbonejs.org/#Events
http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/07/19/references-routing-and-the-event-aggregator-coordinating-views-in-backbone-js/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is absolutely no difference. The definition of underscore's `clone` method is:

```
_.clone = function(obj) {
  if (!_.isObject(obj)) return obj;
  return _.isArray(obj) ? obj.slice() : _.extend({}, obj);
};
```

So if the argument to `_.clone` is an object, the cloning is done via:

```
_.extend({}, obj);
```

Using the `_.extend({}, Backbone.Events)` syntax makes sense, when you also want to define other properties on the new object. Because `extend` accepts any amount of arguments, each of which will be extended into the first argument, it is common to define evented objects as follows:

```
//define an evented object
var foo = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events, {
  bar: function() { /*...*/ }
});
```